# execuable jar file does not work in different folders

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a big project and runs well in Eclipse. I build a runnable jar file by eclipse. When I put the jar file directly on the desktop it runs well, however if I make a new folder and move the jar file to the new folder, it does not work correctly, the output file is empty.. No errors appear.

Comment: do you have some absolute paths in your java code?

Comment: Add logging to your program and check the logs. Errors don't appear, because you're not showing them. You do know how to handle exceptions properly, right?

Comment: try running the jar in command prompt by using `java -jar <yourjar>.jar`

Comment: Have a look inside at the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.  The dependencies are listed there.